# What is pylint "Too many local variables" trying to tell me and what do I do with that?

Tags: python, pylint

I'm working on a python function that reads in Excel or CSV files with various measuring data and spits out a dict, containing strings with the metadata and a pandas dataframe with the data.

```
def reader(file):
"""
blablaba
"""
#500 lines of code
output = {'Error': Errorflag, 'Name': Name, 'Location': Location,
          # 20 more variables
          'Lat': Lat, 'Lon': Lon, 'Number': Number, 'data': data}    
return output
```

The whole thing works well, but pylint tells me `Too many local variables (120/15)pylint(too-many-locals`. So I'm apparently violating 'good' coding style, but I'm wondering where this requirement comes from and what I can do about it.

The [pylint documentation](https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/features.html) just helpfully states "*Too many local variables (%s/%s) Used when a function or method has too many local variables.*" [This site](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:r0914) is a bit more helpful, telling me my function is likely too complex and that I should consider using separate functions.

I could certainly do this, but that would either mean turning `reader` into multiple functions (`location_metadatareader`, `type_metadatareader`, `errorfinder`, `datareader`, ...) which would make using and importing it hell, or I could turn a bunch of things in the function into functions itself, e.g. instead of

```
elevation = elev.replace(",", ".")
elevStart = elevation.find(';')+1
elevEnd = elevation.find('\n')
elevation = elevString1[elevStart:elevEnd]
elev = float(elev)
```

I could encapsulate in in a function

```
def elev(elevation):
    elevation = elev.replace(",", ".")
    elevStart = elevation.find(';')+1
    elevEnd = elevation.find('\n')
    elevation = elevString1[elevStart:elevEnd]
    elev = float(elev)
return(elev)

elev = elev(elevation)
```

adding a bunch more lines without much to gain.

**So, what (besides rethinking the whole function or switching off this part of pylint) are my options? But more important: What's the reason for this style convention? Why should I (or shouldn't I) put in some work to follow it?**

Comment: I would interpret it as an indication that your function is doing too much, and should be broken into smaller functions. But if you think your code is better as it is, ultimately it's up to you and you can ignore the warning.

Comment: Ultimately it's up to you to follow a style guide for python, but there are many good reasons why you'd want to do it, such as making your code clearer, more readable, more optimized... If your method has too many local variables this might mean that your method is way longer than it should be if you were following any good practises. For example, your `reader` method seems to have 500 lines of code. That is way too many lines of code not just for python but for most languages out there. It will still work, but for other devs including yourself it might be a big problem to read that code.

Comment: You say `"turning reader into multiple functions (location_metadatareader, type_metadatareader, errorfinder, datareader, ...) which would make using and importing it hell"`—I don't see why you think breaking up your function into smaller functions would make it harder to use or import. You can still have one central function that calls all the others if that's how you expect it to be used.

Comment: To sum it up, your options are either following a style guide and configuring pylint to skip some rules or be less strict, or just removing pylint and writing code on your own. But trust me, if you choose the second option you'll end up regretting it sooner or later.

Comment: Also, another reason to refactor: properly unit testing a big complex function tends to be **much** more difficult than unit testing several small functions.

Comment: I've got 50 lines of (badly formatted) CSV with metadata as input, each line with many possible errors that need a lot of catching, so that should explain why it is so long, and this also makes it really hard to split it up into parts I can test separately. Just trying to figure out if there's any hard reasons why I should refactor it (which, IMHO would make the code even more complicated to work with) or if it's a rule I can break this time.

Comment: Of course you can break it. It's only a warning. If it's too difficult or not worth your time to improve the code, that's completely valid. No one has unlimited resources.

Comment: maybe one main reason is the principal that functions should do only one thing. As said above, it makes testing (and unit-testing especially) easier, can help readability and debug and therefore maintainability. I agree that Pylint description for this message is unclear. opened a ticket for it https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/8196
I agree with @khelwood, clean code takes effort and is a tradeoff. You can modify the `.rc` file to raise he number of local variables needed to raise this message (`15` in your example), to make the check less harsh and detect only bad cases.

Answer (score 2):

It is basically your choice if you would like to stick to coding conventions. The documentation is quite clear about the convention you are violating:

http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:r0914

> Some programmers consider using several local variables in on function
> or method is an indicator that the function or method is too complex,
> or trying to do too much.

Any modern IDE can be configured to ignore certain error codes. In my IDE of choice (spyder) this looks as follows:

[image]

To be honest: **You have to find out for yourself.** 500 lines of code in a single function looks like **code smell**. **Encapsulating certain parts of the function and moving these parts to helper functions** seems to be the way to go. The reason is simple. Such a large function is **not easy to understand at once**. It is also **difficult to write atomic test cases** - that means your code most certainly allows the control flow to follow **a multitude of different paths through your function instead of only a few.** So in the end it becomes **difficult to test such a function**.